# Set dynamic keys/secret for python-social-auth, before every request used for social auth

Tags: python, django, facebook-oauth, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I am using inside django:
`social-auth-app-django` and `python-social-auth[django]`.
In `settings.py` I have declared the following variables:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {'fields': 'name, email'}
```

Everything works ok. But I want to set the `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY` and the `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET` dynamic before every request for social auth, in an middleware or decorator. Why I want this is, because my  django app is serving data for multiple sites, and every site has is own keys, and his own domain.

I can't find a way to overwrite the variables in settings, or to send the keys to social_auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you have two options:

1. Define your own strategy that overrides [`get_setting()`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/59f8a59052d6cbffd46d364a3480c03261a04868/social_django/strategy.py#L42-L49) and returns the dynamic values as desired (the current `request` is available at `self.request`).

   Then point to it with `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY` setting.
2. Extend `Facebook` backend and override [`get_key_and_secret()`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/1eadf8fa7b13a79363e4fa51ce06e0ae1cc3ca63/social_core/backends/base.py#L243-L247), and return the custom values. Current request is at `self.strategy.request`.

   Then point to it in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting (remove the built-int one).

*Edit:* typography